# Setting max x and y values for Swift

Tags: swift, random, numbers, generator

I was trying to put a random number generator in my code today and I was going to use the maximum x and y values for it. 
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
var rand_x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(maxXValue)) 
var rand_y = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(maxYValue))
```

But I continue to get the error message:

Use of unresolved identifier 'maxXValue' 
Use of unresolved identifier 'maxYValue'

Any tips to fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify what are your `maxXValue` and `maxYValue` it won't work, these values don't exist by default.

Define them as follows :

```
let maxXValue: UInt32 = 200
let maxYValue: UInt32 = 200
```

Obviously these values are examples and you have to choose them yourself.

Comment: When I set a value for X or Y, I get the error message: Cannot invoke 'arc4random_uniform' with an argument list of type '(Int)'

Comment: when you don't specify a type, Swift infer it for you, automatically. In that case, it treats 200 as an `Int`, and `arc4random_uniform` expects `UInt32`.
So, to make it work, just add the type, like: `let maxXValue: UInt32 = 200` and you are good to go.